# System is getting shutdown when battery is low (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate

My system is getting shut down when the battery is low,

I found this on below link also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-lowpower.html.en

I need to set it to suspend or hibernate option.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi @Vivek, if my answer resolved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted (correct) so that other users who has the same issue could also refer to the answer in future

Comment: Hi @KasunSiyambalapitiya, I did the process which you have mentioned but it didn't worked. It goes below critical status and went shutdown after showing the shutdown message.  Settings are getting saved.

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the `dconf` `power` settings after configuring

Comment: It's working now, I need to reboot the system after this process.Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `dconf-editor` for the above. Open up a terminal and run following commands for installing `dconf-editor`.

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dconf-editor -y
```

Once installed you will be able to run it via the shortcut created like follows,
[image]

Next navigate to `power` section as follows,

`org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> power`

and change the value of `critical-battery-action` to your preference (sleep, hibernate and etc).

Comment: Please reboot the system after this process.

Comment: It doesn't work anymore. gnome-settings-daemon only shows a warning but doesn't run any power action. To change settings you need to use UPower config — /etc/UPower/UPower.conf.

Comment: You also need to set use-time-for-policy to false