# Need to set hibernating setting by command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, hibernate

I need to do slove [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076487/system-is-getting-shutdown-when-battary-is-low-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment1838632_1076487) problem by command with d-conf or without it as I need to it every time when I prepare a new system.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'hibernate'
```

Options:

- suspend
- hibernate
- shutdown
- '' (none)

Comment: Yes! it worked Thanks @Rinzwind